# Using cert-manager on AKS with LetsEncrypt and multiple certs

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, cert-manager

Are there any working samples of using cert-manager on AKS with an Nginx ingress where multiple domains have been granted SSL via LetsEncrypt, and then those dns names are directed to separate containers?

I’ve had a single SSL setup for a while, but upon adding a second everything stopped working.

I have several clusters I’ll need to apply this to, so I’m hoping to ind a bullet proof example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I dont think it should matter, i didnt really test that, but if you add 2 individual ingress resources with different domains\secrets, it should work (at least I dont see any reason why it shouldnt):

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tls-example-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: letsencrypt-production
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sslexample.foo.com
    secretName: testsecret-tls
  rules:
    - host: sslexample.foo.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: service1
            servicePort: 80

---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tls-example-ingress
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    certmanager.k8s.io/issuer: letsencrypt-production
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sslexample1.foo.com
    secretName: testsecret-tls1
  rules:
    - host: sslexample1.foo.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: service2
            servicePort: 80
```

tls is an array, so should take more than 1 item. not sure about interaction with cert-manager, though

```
tls:
- hosts:
  - sslexample.foo.com
  secretName: testsecret-tls
- hosts:
  - sslexample1.foo.com
  secretName: testsecret1-tls
```

Comment: Ah! I think I was trying to lump them into one secret. I’ll try that when I’m back. Thanks!

Comment: yeah, they would overwrite each other, i suppose

Comment: Interestingly, that won't work with the `Ingress` kind. That takes a single `secretName`, but many host names...

Do you need multiple ingress kinds, one per-SSL?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for - thankyou, @4c74356b41!

Comment: Saved my day. Thank you for providing this solution. The thing that was also confusing me was the parameter ```secretName```. I thought that it must match a name that should be set somewhere else but apparently it simply sets the name for the tls-secret resource and assigns it to the host it belongs to.

Comment: The latter part rewrites the former one. I'm also looking for a solution to use different certificates on different listeners with kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway

Comment: i'd think you need partial configurations and 2 different controllers? although I'm not sure, not sure why you would downvote me though. seems odd? this question have nothing to do with yours